# Save and Retrieve Selected Spinner Position

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner, sharedpreferences

How would you save and retrieve a spinners selection, so when you come back the same item on the spinner is selected? Maybe with shared preferences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to Save data on the `sharedPreferences`( put this code on the `onItemSelected()` method and save the selected value's position of your `spinner`) :

```
int userChoice = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner",usersChoice);
prefEditor.commit();
```

To get data from `sharedPreferences` :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner",-1);
if(spinnerValue != -1) {
  // set the selected value of the spinner 
  spinner.setSelection(spinnerValue);
}
```

refer this : [set selection in spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection%28int%29)
and this : [get the position of the selected item in a spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29)

### See Also :

- [Android Tutorial : Using SharedPreferences](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sharedpreferences-example/)
- [Android Tutorial : Switch Between Activities and Pass Data Between Them](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/switch-between-activities-in-android/)

Comment: thank you, should the bottom code also be in my onItemSelected() method or in my Loadprefs() method?

Comment: the bottom code  should be on the onCreate() method after finding the spinner views by its id

Comment: I suggest you consider Intents too. As far as I know Shared Pref. is not the best choice here. Cause you don't need to store data on storage and what u need is just past simple data between activities . And for that matter Intents are there to help. They are very easy to use. A quick search will help u along.

Comment: @Tina : good point, but if he wants to save the spinner's selection after restarting the app, in this case, using sharedPreferences is the best way to handle this .

Comment: @Tina : i have added a link to Intents and switching between activities in case he wants to use Intents (y)