# how to get the state of each spinner in a custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom adapter where i display text and a spinner. I have tried to store the state of each spinner so as to display the same items when the activity is open again i have tried different things but i have not been successfull. Please how do i accomplish this thanks. This is the latest thing i have tried

```
    CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> subjects) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_list_view, subjects);
}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, parent, false);

    singleSubject = getItem(position);


    TextView singleText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listSubjectsMyCourses);
    colorLayout = (LinearLayout)customView.findViewById(R.id.colorForSubjects);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) 
   customView.findViewById(R.id.relativeForView);
    parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) 
   customView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    points = new ArrayList<>();
    selected = new ArrayList<>();
    selectedsttring = new ArrayList<>();
 customView.findViewById(R.id.textViewForGrades);
    tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext());



         spinnerForGradePoints = (Spinner)customView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerForGrades);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> gradePointAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, UserCourseSelection2.userSubjectGradePoint);
    spinnerForGradePoints.setAdapter(gradePointAdapter);

    spinnerForGradePoints.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            selectedItempos = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String getSelectedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            tinyDB.putInt("selected", selectedItempos);


        }



        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

  singleText.setText(singleSubject);
    colorLayout.setBackgroundColor(UserCourseSelection2.userSubjectsListColor.get(position));
    int getSelected = tinyDB.getInt("selected");
    spinnerForGradePoints.setSelection(getSelected);

   return customView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is the way if you dont want to use dependency injection like [dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) or some kind of custom local cache on the application level.

For SharedPreferences in spinner check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13431729/5577679

Comment: i used sharedpreferences before, i don't know how i will save each spinner in sharedpreferences since it's not just one spinner the spinner is generated from a layout and i am using a custom adapter to show it

Comment: Look on the link i posted then. That is the answer for SharedPrefs for spinner.

Comment: i have used sharedpreferences before. It works but the problem i had with it was that it brought back the state of the last one selected in my case in other words it took the state of the last spinner selected and used it for all the spinners so all the spinners had the same items. I want them to have different items

Comment: i have just edited the code this is how i used the sharedPrefrences which is the tinyDB just take the tinyDB as sharedprefrences, they are the same thing. I have tried to use loops to see if i can make them have different values but to no avail. I am open to suggestions

Comment: I can agree with you on that matter but can't help you any further I'm afraid. In every case you should have some sort of cache, that's for sure. You decide which one will you use.