# How to Save Spinner Position with Shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences, spinner

I am making an android app that asks for the users to select a Bluetooth paired device via spinner.

When the user opens the app first time, user selects a Bluetooth paired device** from list. Then when app opens second time, I want the same Bluetooth paired device to be selected. I don't want user to select the paired device every time the app is opened. How to do that?

```
Spinner btPairedDevicesSpinner;  
BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothDevice [] mBluetoothDeviceArray; 

btPairedDevicesSpinner = findViewById(R.id.btPairedDevicesSpinner);
mGetBluetoothPairedDevice ();
btPairedDevicesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mPairedDeviceOnItemSelectedListener);

public void mGetBluetoothPairedDevice () {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
      mBluetoothDeviceArray = new BluetoothDevice[mPairedDevice.size()];
        String [] strings = new String[mPairedDevice.size()];
        int index = 0;
        if (mPairedDevice.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : mPairedDevice) {
                mBluetoothDeviceArray [index] = device;
                strings [index] = device.getName();
                index++;
            }
        }
        else {
            String mOnDevice = "No Device found";
            mPairedDeviceArrayAdapter.add(mOnDevice);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
        btPairedDevicesSpinner.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }

private final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mPairedDeviceOnItemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mBluetoothDeviceArray [i], view);
            mConnectThread.start();

            mBluetoothToolBar.setSubtitle("Connecting");
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            Toast.makeText(BluetoothMain.this, "Nothing is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: i just find my answer here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431644/save-and-retrieve-selected-spinner-position)

Answer (score 0):

One way that should work. Store the selected device name in shared preferences. (Create the sharedPref object somewhere else like onCreate() and do the edit in spinners onItemChanged() )

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
sharedPref.edit().putString("btDeviceName", "the name").apply();
```

After calling
btPairedDevicesSpinner.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
load the device name from shared preferences and if there is one call setSelection() on spinner

```
String deviceName = sharedPref.getString("btDeviceName", null);
if(deviceName != null){
     btPairedDevicesSpinner.setSelection(mArrayAdapter.getPosition("deviceName "));
}
```